# How to start Terminator on a different monitor?

Tags: terminator

I have 3 monitors, and when I start terminator it opens on monitor 1 which is to my left, but I would like it to open on monitor 3, to my right.

I do not wish to simply swap monitor 1 for 3 in my monitor configuration as monitor 1 has other significance.

Is there a command I could use on the terminal that starts an application on a different monitor?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is the use of **position** variable of the specific Window configuration on the terminator config.

For example, in a case with two monitors (1920x1080), the following layout configuration will open a terminal window on the second monitor in fullscreen mode.

```
[[[Window]]]
type = Window
parent = ""
fullscreen = True
position = 1700:0
size = 500, 500
[[[Term]]]
type = Terminal
parent = Main
...
```

Comment: This solution is not very useful in cases when you connect monitors in different layouts, in my case, I had monitor on top, and configured as you recommended, but once I connect another monitor in the left, I need to reconfigure it again... is there any other option?

Comment: It opens perfectly on second monitor. But i would like it to open in a third monitor... How to do the calculations for the third monitor? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

with CompizConfig Settings Manager you can act on windows placement.

Install ccsm :

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins
```

- Launch it : `ccsm`
- Select "Windows Management"
- Select "Place Windows"
- Change the placement mode

select "Windows Management"